# Live 360° Panorama Image Stitching implementation

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, image-stitching, 360-panorama

I am planning to implement a live 360° panorama stitcher having 6 cameras of the same model.

I came across the stitching_detailed.cpp implementation from OpenCV. The problem is that it takes around 1 second to stitch only 2 images together using my desired parameters, which is fairly slow.

As my application should be ran in real-time. I need to be able to stitch 6 images together in around 100 ms for it to be "acceptable". The output resolution should be around 0.2 Megapixels. Therefore, I am starting to do my own implementation in C++, based pretty much on what is done on stitchig_detailed. I am aiming to use as much as possible the CUDA functions on OpenCV (some of them are not even implemented stitching_detailed).

I have been carefully studying the stitching pipeline on which the previous algorithm is based, as described in [Images stitching by OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/d46/group__stitching.html) and in the paper [Automatic Panoramic Image Stitching using Invariant Features](http://Automatic%20Panoramic%20Image%20Stitching%20using%20Invariant%20Features).

As the stitching pipeline is too general, **there are several assumptions I have made in order to simplify it and speed it up, I would like to get some feedback to know if they are valid:**

- All the images I will provide to the algorithm are for sure part of the panorama image. So I do not have to extra check on that.
- The 6 cameras will be fixed in position and orientation. Therefore, I know beforehand the order in which the cameras need to be stitched into the panorama picture. I can therefore avoid trying to match images from cameras that are not contiguous.
- As the cameras are going to remain static. It would be valid to perform the registration step in order to get the camera orientation Matrix R only once (as a kind of initialization). Afterwards, I could only perform the compositing block for subsequent frames. (Again all this assuming the cameras remain completely static).

**I also have the following questions...**

- I can indeed calibrate the cameras prior to my application and obtain each of the intrinsic camera parameters Matrix K and its respective distortion parameters. Could I plug K into the stitching pipeline and therefore avoid the K calculation in the registration step?
- What other thing (if any) could  camera calibration bring into the pipeline? Distortion correction?
- If my previous assumption about executing only the compositing block is correct... Could I still take out some parts of it? My guess is that maybe the seam finder should be ran only once (in the initialization of the algorithm).
- Is exposure compensation needed at all for my application case? (As the cameras are literally the same).

Any lead would be deeply appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you can do to reduce your progressing time is to calibrate your camera so that you don't need to process images to find homography matrices based on features. Find them beforehand so that they are constant matrix

Comment: thanks, actually that is what I did so far. Now I am dealing with ghosting problems as my cameras are separated relatively from each other. Therefore, I am violating one of the main assumptions of planar homography model.

Comment: I saw another post of you asking about speeding up finding seams process. Did you solve that problem? I did re-implemented it using Boykov's implementation on GraphCut algorithm in CPU but I have been racking my brain to implement it on CUDA but it still not work. Do you have any idea??

Comment: No, unfortunately I am still running it on CPU. In order to speed it up I am temporarily using a Voronoi Seam Finder, although the quality of the seam is of course not comparable. I hope that OpenCV officially implements a CUDA version soon.

Comment: Not really, since I searched google and found that there was actually a function called cv::cuda::graphcut() for our problem but it was removed since it is not compatible with CUDA version higher than 8.0. I found an implementation for graphCut in CUDA described in paper CudaCuts:Fast graphcut on GPU and its project page on this [link](http://vibhavvineet.info/code.html) but only applying for image segmentation. I have been racking my brain to switch it to image Texture Synthesis. You can adopt it and if you find something useful, please let me know

Comment: Everything we need to do is change the graph construction from image segmentation problem to Image Texture Synthesis since the core algorithm(maxflow/min-cut algorithm) is the same for both cases. I successfully apply it on CPU (the implementation of Boykov) but when I used the same graph construction for CUDA implementation by Vibhav Vineet, the result is dissapointing. Maybe you can find something and help both of us

Comment: Actually. I found that their implementation in CUDA is only applicable for image segmentation and their method is not general for solving the maxflow/min-cut algorithm, at least for the kind of graph that I constructed. There is some corner cases that they missed

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I just got back to it and came by this post from you [link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/234209/cudacuts-for-image-texture-synthesis/), we are basically trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I have failed to modify the CUDA implementation for my application. I emailed the author to ask for more detail but there is no response so I find a way to workaround. I minimize the overlap region between the 2 images so that the execution time of Boykov implementation is acceptable for my application(Not as fast as CUDA code but it is ok). In my case, I fixed the overlap region to be 30 pixels